# x86 linux kernel development in qemu

Tags: linux, x86, kernel, qemu, busybox

I built the stable linux kernel image and now I'm trying to run it with qemu.

I build the rootfs.img using busybox by following the instructions [here](http://emreboy.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/building-a-root-file-system-using-busybox/) (took out ARM stuff)

Now, when I run I get the following error:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -m 512M -kernel bzImage -initrd rootfs.img -append “root=/dev/ram rdinit=/sbin/init”
qemu-system-x86_64: -append “root=/dev/ram: could not open disk image rdinit=/sbin/init”: Could not open 'rdinit=/sbin/init”': No such file or directory
```

There seems to be a problem with "root=/dev/ram"? /sbin/init is inside the image.

Not sure what to do from here.  Would someone be able to provide the steps they use to compile the kernel and run on qemu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress typography features strike again! You're using the wrong kind of quotation marks:

```
-append “root=/dev/ram rdinit=/sbin/init”
        ^                               ^
```

The indicated characters are, respectively, U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK and U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (i.e, "curly quotes"), not normal quotation marks.

Retype the command line by hand (or, at least, those two characters) and it'll work correctly.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this was it! I would never have thought that was the issue.